# React Firebase onSnapshot Method - Inconsistent Behavior of Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am using Next.js framework.
I am trying to fetch data using the onSnapshot method in Firebase.
I'm curious about the **inconsistent behavior of the custom function(`warningEmptyData`)**, which displays a modal when the fetched data is empty.

The scenario assumes that the data is empty,
and there have been no changes to the data since the component mounted for the first time.

```
const [listData,setListData] = useState()
...
useEffect(() => {
    const queryLists = query(
      //code about query
    );

    const fetchLists = onSnapshot(queryLists, (snapshot) => {
      const datas = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
      setListsData(datas);
      warningEmptyData(datas);1️⃣
    });
    
    const warningEmptyData = (data: any[]) => {
      if (data.length < 1) {
        Modal.warning({
          //code about warning contents
      }
    };
    return () => {
      fetchLists();
      warningEmptyData(datas);2️⃣
  }, []);
```

When I call the function at position 1️⃣, the modal only appears once.
However, when I call the function at position 2️⃣, the modal appears twice.
I would like to understand why this is happening.

Based on GPT, it seems that the issue might be related to re-rendering caused by changes in useState.
However, I'm having trouble understanding it well.
Since it's the initial mount and there are no data changes.
I've set the dependency array as [], so shouldn't it be irrelevant?

Comment: ***Why*** are you calling `fetchLists` and `warningEmptyData` in the `useEffect` hook's cleanup function? Maybe it's poor formatting or an incomplete code example, but from what I can tell also, `datas` looks to be undefined in the cleanup function. If you are running React 18 and rendering the app into a `React.StrictMode` component this will do a double mounting of the component in non-production builds as a check for ensuring reusable state, so this may be why you see `warningEmptyData` called more often than you are expecting.

Comment: "I'm grateful for informing me about `React.StrictMode`. The issue I was curious about has been resolved.
Also, I had a misunderstanding about the **cleanup function** in useEffect. I realized why putting `warningEmptyData` there is not allowed.
However, there is also an issue with calling `fetchLists` in the cleanup function. I thought it was acceptable to call `fetchLists in the cleanup` to clean up the previously executed onSnapshot."

Comment: Ah, I see, yeah, if `onSnapshot` returns an "unsubscribe" function (*which I'm sure it does*), then yes, the `useEffect` hook's cleanup function is where you'd call it to unsubscribe the snapshot subscription. It could probably be renamed to provide better context what its purpose is.

Comment: I understand. It could be batter renaming the function. Thank you for helping me so much!